# What is valid query string for null array item?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I have the object:

```
{
  "items": [ null, 1, 2 ]
}
```

and two versions of query strings for it:

1. `array=null&array=1&array=2`
2. `array=&array=1&array=2`

Which of them is proper? Is there any commonly used convention for this case?

**Upd:** the problem with `null` is that ASP.NET interprets it as `"null"` string.

Comment: If it is in query string, it is a string and if you read it in any application weather asp.net, java, php you will get null as string.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what the recipient application expects and parses.

The thing is, though, receiving "null", "false" etc from the query string will of course be interpreted as a string value, and therefore falsy.

So in the URL some_script.php?foo=false

```
if (!empty($_GET['foo'])) //true - contaisn "false", a string, not a boolean
```

If you want to be sure the parameter is therefore evaluated to falsy, I would suggest passing it empty.